# How to create an ami image of instance and terminate the instance at the same time for m4 series

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ami

I am trying to create an ami of my instance so if i am creating an ami for m4 series instance types and as soon as ami creation gets started , i am terminating the instances so the ami status gets failed but when i do this steps for c5 series of instance type its working properly .

why such strange behaviour and what should i do to know why for m4 series its failing and how to create an ami and terminate the instance simultaneously because if i have for creating an ami it can take some time more than 5 mins also

Comment: Verify DeletionOnTermination attribute on each instance's EBS volume. If you terminate an instance and EBS volumes are deleted you won't be able to take snapshots/create AMI image.

Comment: But the same is working for the c5 series